# Add a boolean field if a row exists in another table?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-1.7

I have two tables called `Post` and `Reply`. The users can create just one `Response` for each `Post`. The models look like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

class Reply(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = 'replies')
```

Now, I have a view that returns the posts, like this:

```
class PostList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

And a serializer for the posts:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

The results of this view look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "The first post"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "The second post"
    }
]
```

Now, to the actual problem in question: I'd like to have a boolean field in the results that'd be `true` if the user has replied to the post, and `false` if they hasn't. Basically, the result for a situation where the current user has replied to the first post but not the second post would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "The first post",
        "replied": "true"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "The second post",
        "replied": "false"
    }
]
```

How do I achieve this? I have a hunch that this should be implemented in the serializer somehow, but I don't know how I'd do that.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: The first idea is to add custom serializer method field in your serializer ( http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield ), but keep in mind that you have to have current user object in your serializer class ( eg, you can override the serializer constructor to pass it ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piggybacking off of dydek's answer here.

You overwrite your [get_queryset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) in the Api View

```
class PostList(generics.ListAPIView):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        Post.objects.all().extra(select={
        'current_user_replies_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <reply table> WHERE' +
        'post_id=posts_post.id AND owner_id = %s'
                                  },select_params=(request.user.id,))
```

This will add 'current_user_replies_count' as a property to the Post objects in your queryset.

Comment: can you explain `post_id=posts_post.id` relation? Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom fields to your `PostSerializer`

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    replied = serializers.SerializerMethodField('has_replies')

    def has_replies(post):
        return post.replies.filter(owner=self.context["request"].user).exists()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'replied')
```

Comment: The problem is whether the `request.user` has replied to the post, not any user

Comment: I see, you can access to the `request` inside a serializer via `self.context["request"]`. The context is set by `ListAPIView.get_serializer_context` method. Assuming that the `Reply` object has a field called `owner`, you can use the answer above.

Comment: Doesn't this cause the extra query in `has_replies()` to be executed once per row in the original query?

Answer (score 1):

The next problem here is to many sql queries when you'll be fetching eg. 100 objects (you will have BASE_QUERIES_COUNT + len(objects) ). Of corse we don't want to have linear sql queries count, and this situation 
should never happen, especially in production version. The perfect
solution here would be if we would be able to have all data fetched in 
one sql query. This is possible with override `get_queryset` method ( here https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L47 ). And then queryset could look like below, param `current_user_replies_count` is available as normal model instance variable.

```
# all only for example
Post.objects.all().extra(select={
        'current_user_replies_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <reply table> WHERE '+
                                      'post_id=posts_post.id AND owner_id = %s'
    },
    select_params=(request.user.id,)
)
```

I haven't tested it, so use it more as example instead of ready solution, 
and you should cast current_user_replies_count to bool.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how exactly I should implement this in my code.