# Get one related object in single request for Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-related-manager

I have this models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="like_user", blank=False, null=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name="like_book", blank=False, null=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["user", "book"]
```

I want get all books and check if current user liked each book in single request

`Book.objects.select_related('like_book').all()`

won't work because of many results

`Book.objects.prefetch_related('like_book').all()`

will cache `like_set` but it will contain all likes for this Book. Not only one for this user.

In the end i want to have additional field `is_liked`

```
books = Book.objects.MAGIC_FETCH('like_book', user=self.request.user).all()
books[0].is_liked
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer which is doing something very similar to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30650380/3955830

Comment: @solarissmoke it is very close to what I want. I think I could use it as answer to my question. But it is still interesting if it is any way to do this more elegant without external query. But thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*** Updated to address comments ***

So roughly speaking, I think this is what you would use:

```
Book.objects.annotate(is_liked=Case(When(like__user=self.request.user, then=True), default=False))
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to filter books which the current user has liked, but rather to fetch all books, but annotate the ones liked by the current user.

Comment: @solarissmoke is right. I want ALL books and annotate the ones liked by the current user

Comment: @2ps it is so awesome! Thank You!

Comment: I've made it like this:
`Book.objects.annotate(is_liked=Case(
            When(like_book__user=self.request.user, then=Value(True)),
            default=Value(False), output_field=BooleanField()))`